# calculating np.npv at a monthly rate

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance

I am calculating the net present value using the np.npv calculator. My initial investment is 19,000, my yearly discount rate is 6.1% and my positive cash flow, which starts at the 6th month, is 9,0000 (before I have 0 cash flow).

```
inv = -19000
rate = 0.061
cf = 90000
```

According to the np.npv formula, this would give me the return after the first 12 months:

```
return = np.npv(rate, [inv, cf*6])
```

what about at six month?

```
six = np.npv(rate/2, [inv, cf])
```

is this correct?

Comment: Just to clarify - you say cash flow "starts at the 6th month" - do you mean the 7th month (so cash flow is 90,000 X6)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with numpy. After looking at the docs, I think the following for 12 months might be like this.

`L = [-19000] + [0]*5 + [90000]*6`

`np.npv(rate / 12, L)`

gives, `498240.3962008157`

I am not sure why the first month is negative. But this period would be for the first month of -19000, 5 months of 0, and 6 months of 90000.

Really, to get the present value of these cash flows, I would make the initial payment positive.